# Route 53 not able to map to EC2 using an Elastic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-ip

So I launched an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP attached to it. I am able to see my app online (HTTP) using the IP address (52.88.100.62).

I bought a domain name (rishijavia.com) and was trying to link the instance to that using Route 53. Here's a screenshot of the [Route 53 Settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJIAj.jpg)

First I thought that the problem was with nameservers not being associated properly, but [they are all configured properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWRJ8.jpg) and match with the Route 53 nameservers.

I don't know what's the problem now. I also tried with a different instance with its temporary public IP but no luck.

I also tried A record instead of CNAME with Name of "www.rishijavia.com" instead of "*.rishijavia.com" but it didn't help either.

Comment: It looks like it is working already.

Comment: I wouldn't set a TTL of 48 hours! 300 seconds is more than enough, even as low as 60 is just fine for Route 53. High TTL means any change made in your records will take this amount of time to propagate so with 48 hours TTL - it'll take at least two days to see your changes propagating to all resolvers as they'll be caching the old values for 48 hours at least. A TTL of 60 seconds ensures old changes are removed from caches very quickly, at least after a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hostname(s) are resolving properly for me. What you're seeing is likely due to cached records in your resolver needing to expire.

Comment: Yes, tried it on my phone using data. I think the records were cached with my ISP for 2 days (172800 seconds). Thank you! (ah, I feel dumb now).